# How do I Handle Right click Operation in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am Writing a code for to handle right click operation, element should open in new tab, but it's not working.Help me with this

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.ContextClick(element).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click in Selenium is also called Context Click, pre-defined method context click provided by Actions class is used to perform right click operation. Below is the code to demonstrate right click operation using Actions class.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.id("ID"));
actions.contextClick(elementLocator).perform();
```

[Source](https://www.guru99.com/double-click-and-right-click-selenium.html)

Comment: I am doing the same things it's not working.And it is only for right click operation, what I want, after right click operation, I want to select an option like open a new tab. For this I want a script.